# Li over floated div

Tags: html, css, position, html-lists

I have **div.content** that holds **div.images** which is left floated and next to it is a list with couple of items.

The problem is that **li's apear over div.images** element. I've tried to make list inline-block but in this case items that appear under the div.images are positioned next to the right edge of div.images.

http://jsfiddle.net/kmZ3X/

Any idea?

Comment: add float left to the ul list

Comment: If I add float left to the ul it will stick at the right edge of the div.images element and all li's that are under div.images element will   not move to the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `list-style-position: inside` on the li elements.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/psJyh/

Answer (score 0):

add

```
ul{
float: left
}
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

this will make it appear below the images
css:

```
 .content p, .content ul {clear:both}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="content">
 <img alt="Desert" src="images/Desert.jpg"/>
 <p>sth.</p>
</div>
```

```
div.content img
   {display: block;float: left; margin-right: 10px;border: solid 1px #999;padding: 5px; }
```

if you have a list instead of paragraph it will be same. if you have any problem you can ask me again. thank you.